# .NET Localization not working

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, localization, internationalization

I've created a localized winforms application (in VS2008) by setting the `Localizable` property to `true` and then editing the texts, etc... of my Mainform in the designer for the relevant language.

I also have some localized strings that the application needs (e.g. for displaying message boxes and such...). Those strings I have stored in a files named

- strings.resx
- strings.de.resx
- ... and so on

When I set the application's language via `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` it seems to work, but only within Visual Studio. When I create a release executable and double click it, the Winforms always uses the default language (even if I hardcode `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ...` in there...

I also tried setting `strings.Culture` and `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture`, that didn't work either

thx for any help

Comment: are the other dll files reachable by your exe?

Comment: ha! did't even know about dll's. I thought the strings would be compiled into the exe file. I copied the dll's over and now it works. thx.

Comment: i'll post this as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ensure that the additionally created DLLs are accessible by your EXE.